# Convert String To correct date

Tags: swift

I'm working on event application. I'm let the user create the event and save it in DB to remind him. now I'm facing an issue when the user put the date as string and from my code when I'm trying to convert it to date formate it gives me wrong date. for example if the user put in the text "01-03-2018 10:00" after convert it to date it returns to me "2017-12-24 10:00:00 +0000".
here is my code

```
let startDateFormatter = DateFormatter()

startDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"

startDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

startDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let d = "01-03-2018 10:00”

let startDate = startDateFormatter.date(from: d)

print(startDate!)
```

so any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it. it regarding to date formatter, when I changed the date formatter form `startDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm`”
to

```
endDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
endDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

` worked with me. I shared the answer if anyone faced the same issue

Comment: `TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")`. Btw the correct date format for the date string you posted in your question is  `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm”`